# Regex replace IF a variable does not match a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regexp with replace for use in a java embedded application that will pass a URL through an on click.  What I have so far is

`(bi.)(.*\.)([^.]+)(.com)$` with replace set to `$2$3$4`

This, however, does not allow for passing to environments without the second variable.  What I need is something that will say `IF .*\. is prd001 THEN '' ELSE .*\.` I need to negate the prd001 where it exists, but pass that portion through if it is anything else in the substitution portion.

I am very new to these concepts and if you ask what language this is for, I probably could not tell you other than our application is written in JAVA.  I do know I will need escape characters later, and am confident in that portion.  Just lost with the regex.  Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your request and your original regex is correct (I thought you might have meant `bi\.` in the initial capture group), the following should work:

```
(bi.)(?:(?:prd001\.)|(.*\.))([^.]+)(.com)
```

as shown in http://rubular.com/r/oU1ls2Gy6x and http://rubular.com/r/YDhYObKe1c

The `?:` construct tells the regex machinery to match the following expression but *not* create a capture group. So the second capture group will be empty if any only if `prod001.` is not present there.

Comment: Your rubular link only has one example url. Add an example for a non prod url, and maybe other edge cases

Comment: @Bohemian Do you know how to do that (include multiple test strings) within a single Rubular?

Comment: @Bohemian I added a non-prod test string, but given the ambiguities in the question, I'm not sure what edge cases to include.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I am testing this in notepad++ but it is not exluding 'prd001.'  The examples I am working with are:

What is input > What I need
`bi.bidev-30000.123.com > bidev-30000.123.com`,
`bi.prd001.123.com > 123.com`,
`bi.test30000.123.com > test30000.123.com`

Comment: I am perplexed as to how it is working in Rubular but not in Notepad++.  Maybe limitations there?  I am going to implement it in the application test space and see what happens.

Comment: I mistakenly had `prod001` instead of `prd001`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Was it just the `prd001` example that didn't work? They all work for me in Sublime 2. Is Notepad a reference to Windows' Notepad?

Comment: I got it, and you were correct.  The difference was my exclude is prd001 and you had prod001.  Thanks again for the help.  This saved me big time and covers all of my possible edge cases!

Comment: Just curious about one thing. Did you really intend `bi.` in the initial capture group rather than `bi\.`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the regex to `(bi.)(.*\.)?([^.]+)(.com)$`

Now it will only use the `(.*\.)` if it is present, and thus if not present the `$2` will be empty.

Comment: I did end up incorporating the question mark in order to be sure to gather examples such as bi.123.com.  Thanks for this, it was a great help, but alone it was not the answer.